# Loading a javascript dynamically in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, dom, angular6, domcontentloaded

I have got the following scenario and problem to solve. Any help will be appreciated.

Scenario
I have an angular application which calls a service(web api) and gets the contents back. The content is added to the html div. The content is as follow:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://xxxx.com/ws/js/xxxxloader.js" id="theLoader"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// The code here look at the if the above script has been loaded properly by //checking the state of above script tag
</script>
```

I am adding the returned content to the HTML of the component in NgOnInit() as follow.

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.apiService.getContent().subscribe(           
                        d => {
                  this.responseString = d.toString();                


                   var frag = document.createRange().createContextualFragment(this.responseString);
                   document.getElementById("theContainer").appendChild(frag);

                        }
                    );
                }
```

However, it is failing because the first script tag (#theLoader) has never been loaded properly. I think it is because I am injecting the script tag after Dom has finished loading.
If you can see the better way of injecting the script, can you enlighten me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically inject the JS URL by creating dynamic script tag

```
ngOnInit(){
    function loadScripts(url: string){
        var el = document.createElement('script');
        el.onload = function(script){
            console.log(script + ' loaded!');
            // you can call the JS Function
        };
        el.src = url;
        document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].append(el);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Guys, Thanks for your answers. It seems the problem is that when the service has returned with Script tag, angular has already loaded the dom. That's why it is not loading script tag properly. Any input will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
ngAfterViewInit () {
    this.loadScript('path to your js');           
}

loadScript(url) {
    console.log('preparing to load...')
    let node = document.createElement('script');
    node.src = url;
    node.type = 'text/javascript';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(node);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
 ngOnInit(){
  this.addScripts("https://xxxx.com/ws/js/xxxxloader.js", 'text/javascript');
  this.addScripts("https://xxxx.com/js/mail.js", 'text/javascript');
}

addScripts(src, type): void{
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = src;
    script.type = type;
    document.querySelector('body').appendChild(script);
}
```